# Как удалить все комментарии в ruamel.yaml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

Имеется YAML вида:

```
objects:
# Comment Moscow
  - name: Moscow
# Comment London
  - name: London
# Comment NewYork
  - name: New York
# Comment Berlin
  - name: Berlin
...
```

Как удалить все комментарии?

---

UPD:
PyYAML не подходит, т.к. в YAML есть многострочные ключи, которые PyYAML передает некорректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал следующим образом:

```
for object in fin['objects']:
    del object.ca.comment
```

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее надежный вариант - просто прочитать YAML файл в словарь и записать его обратно в YAML файл. Парсер YAML сам удалит все комментарии.

```
# from yaml import safe_load, safe_dump   #  pip install pyyaml
from ruamel.yaml import safe_dump, safe_load  #  pip install ruamel.yaml

with open(r"D:\download\test.yml", "r") as fin, \
     open(r"D:\download\test_new.yml", "w") as fout:
    data = safe_load(fin)
    safe_dump(data, fout)
```

---

Исходный файл:

```
objects:
  - name: "# - isn't a comment!"
# Comment Moscow
  - name: Moscow
# Comment London
  - name: London
# Comment NewYork
  - name: New York
# Comment Berlin
  - name: Berlin
```

---

Результат:

```
objects:
- name: '# - isn''t a comment!'
- name: Moscow
- name: London
- name: New York
- name: Berlin
```